# How to extract the value of the field on user-command(click) for interactive ALV?

Tags: abap, alv

The below code is the form which will pop up the new window after clicking on the hotspot enabled field. I want to print the value of the field (hotspot enabled) that is clicked.

```
FORM user_command USING r_ucomm TYPE sy-ucomm
                    rs_selfield TYPE slis_selfield.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: @vwegert Here I am not supposed to provide the whole code. Only the snippets that are not working have been provided here. And it is by the way obvious that there will be a perform for the given form. Hope this helps.

Comment: A little more context would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you talk about the ALV Grid. So you use a FM called **REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY**. There is a exporting parameter called **I_callback_user_command**. In this parameter you have to set the form name of your program. For Example:

```
 CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    i_bypassing_buffer      = 'X'
    it_fieldcat             = lt_fieldcat
    i_callback_program      = sy-repid
    i_save                  = 'A'
    i_callback_user_command = 'USER_COMMAND'
    is_variant              = ls_variant
  TABLES
    t_outtab                = lt_qmel_mat
  EXCEPTIONS
    program_error           = 1
    OTHERS                  = 9.
IF sy-subrc <> 0.
  MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
          WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
ENDIF.
```

And the Form:

```
FORM user_command USING rf_ucomm LIKE sy-ucomm
                    selfield TYPE slis_selfield.
 DATA: lv_qmnum      TYPE qmnum.
 CASE selfield-fieldname.
  WHEN 'QMNUM'.
   "Code
 ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.
```

I hope that helps you.